Confusion on metric compatability of the dual metric tensor.
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. For 1-forms $\omega,\tau$ we identify that $g(\omega,\tau)=g(\omega^\sharp,\tau^\sharp)$. In Petersen's Riemannian geometry theorem 9.2.8 there is proof of Kato's inequality where we have the step $d|\omega|^2=2g(\nabla\omega,\omega)$. I understand that
$d|\omega|^2=2g(\nabla(\omega^\sharp),\omega^\sharp)$ by metric compatability of Levi-Civita connection. But I don't get why $g(\nabla(\omega^\sharp),\omega^\sharp)=g(\nabla\omega,\omega)$.

found answer I was looking for
